# Really detect Browser support Javascript by C#.NET 2.0 or higher?

Tags: javascript

I need to detect the Browser has support Javascript by C#.NET 2.0 code. But the `Request.Browser.Javascript` do not work correct now for all Browser.

I really need other way to detect it, who can tell me know also everyone here with the same problem.

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Please use `new HttpBrowserCapabilities().JavaScript` instead

Comment: Object not instance, Thanks !

Comment: Please new the HttpBrowserCapabilities object first

Answer (score 0):

When you say C# .NET 2.0 code, are you referring to ASP.NET or Silverlight?  I assume ASP.NET.  Regardless, browser detection is a pretty unreliable source of information about the client's capabilities.  What are you really trying to find out?  If you need to ensure that the client has Javascript enabled, one method is to include html code like `<noscript>This page requires javascript</noscript>`.  This is a pretty common way to provide fallback error information (ie that your code requires Javascript in order to work properly).

Comment: Yes, I used code C# to detect the Browser JavaScript enabled then redirect to link1 else redirect link2. So, I can not use <noscript>, I like redirect when on web server, not client redirect. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Check this link at [Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+ScottHanselmanASPNET+%28Scott+Hanselman%27s+Computer+Zen+-+ASPNET%29) blog, it describes the problem as you have suggested. And also check out this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3yekbd5b.aspx) link.

**Code sample from MSDN:**

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    System.Web.HttpBrowserCapabilities browser = Request.Browser;
    string s = "Browser Capabilities\n"
        + "Type = "                    + browser.Type + "\n"
        + "Name = "                    + browser.Browser + "\n"
        + "Version = "                 + browser.Version + "\n"
        + "Major Version = "           + browser.MajorVersion + "\n"
        + "Minor Version = "           + browser.MinorVersion + "\n"
        + "Platform = "                + browser.Platform + "\n"
        + "Is Beta = "                 + browser.Beta + "\n"
        + "Is Crawler = "              + browser.Crawler + "\n"
        + "Is AOL = "                  + browser.AOL + "\n"
        + "Is Win16 = "                + browser.Win16 + "\n"
        + "Is Win32 = "                + browser.Win32 + "\n"
        + "Supports Frames = "         + browser.Frames + "\n"
        + "Supports Tables = "         + browser.Tables + "\n"
        + "Supports Cookies = "        + browser.Cookies + "\n"
        + "Supports VBScript = "       + browser.VBScript + "\n"
        + "Supports JavaScript = "     + 
            browser.EcmaScriptVersion.ToString() + "\n"
        + "Supports Java Applets = "   + browser.JavaApplets + "\n"
        + "Supports ActiveX Controls = " + browser.ActiveXControls 
              + "\n"
        + "Supports JavaScript Version = " +
            browser["JavaScriptVersion"] + "\n";

    TextBox1.Text = s;
}
```

I strongly hope it solves your problem.

Comment: Yes, I used code C# to detect the Browser JavaScript enabled then redirect to link1 else redirect link2. So, I tested your code, But still do not fix my issue with detect JavaScript enabled or disabled. Your result always show correct value when I test disable or enable js. Thanks !

Comment: Have you checked this link - http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx